# MongoDb not found in ZF2 controller

Tags: php, mongodb, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have few controllers in my zf2 project which work perfectly in the browser using apache and via command line.

However, I recently installed MongoDb so I can store some data using the driver found in (http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php)

My issue is, when I try to access the driver via controller + browser, I get the following message error in my apache logs :

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MongoDb\Driver\Manager' not found.
'MongoDb\Driver\Manager' is the namespace for this Driver.

If I execute some other controllers via command line, MongoDb works correctly.

Does anyone know why is this happening? I cannot see the issue :(

Thank you

Comment: debug with phpinfo(), you'll see the extension is not properly installed. command-line and web versions might use different php.ini files.

Comment: @Calimero I can see 

MongoDB Support enabled
Version 1.6.14

with phpinfo running from the controller in my web browser, so I suppose extension is installed properly

Comment: post your code then, highlighting the line pointed to by the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that my php.ini was pointing to mongo.so instead of mongodb.so

That fixed the issue
http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.manual.php

Thank you for your help